# For a given word calculate the number of possible anagrams

Tags: c#, arrays, string, algorithm, anagram

For a given word calculate the number of possible anagrams.
The resulting words do not have to exist in the dictionary.
Anagrams do not have to be repeated and anagrams do not have to be generated, only their number calculated.

The last test is not working and I do not know how should I make it work. Can you help me, please?

**Here is my code:**

```
    using System;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string word = Console.ReadLine();
        int wordLenth = word.Length;
        int sameLetter = 1;

        for (int i=0;i<wordLenth;i++)
        {
            for (int j=i+1;j<wordLenth;j++)
            {
                if (word[i]==word[j])
                {
                    sameLetter++;
                }
            }
        }
        int firstResult=1, secondResult=1, lastResult;
        for (int i=1; i <= wordLenth; i++)
        {
            firstResult *= i;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= sameLetter; i++)
        {
            secondResult *= i;
        }
        lastResult = firstResult / secondResult;
        Console.WriteLine(lastResult);     
    }
```

```
Results:

Compilation successfully executed.
Test 1: Correctly calculate the number of anagrams for "abc" - successful
Test 2: Correctly calculate the number of anagrams for "abc" - success
Test 3: Correctly calculates the number of anagrams for "aaab" - failed
Expected results: "4"
Results obtained: "1"
```

The submitted solution does not correctly calculate the number of unique anagrams if there are repeating letters.

Comment: Your solution can't work, because you only check for `sameLetter` once, but what if you have two or more letters who get repeated, like in "aaabbbcccdddd"?

Comment: You can solve this also with some math, e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114654/permutations-of-subsets-of-a-multiset/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have word of length `n` with `m` distinct letters `w1, ..., wm` where `wi` is occurence of `i`th letter,
the number of possible anagrams is

**Math:**

```
N = n! / w1! / w2! / ... / wm!
```

**For instance:**

1. For `abc` we have `n = 3`, `m = 3`, `w1 = w2 = w3 = 1`:

```
N = 3! / 1! / 1! / 1! = 6 / 1 / 1 / 1 = 6
```

2. For `aaab`  we have `n = 4`, `m = 2`, `w1 = 3, w2 = 1`:

```
N = 4! / 3! / 1! = 24 / 6 / 1 = 4
```

**Code:**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics;

...

private static BigInteger Factorial(int value) {
  BigInteger result = 1;

  for (int i = 2; i <= value; ++i)
    result *= i;

  return result;
}

private static BigInteger CountAnagrams(string value) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    return 1;

  return value
    .GroupBy(c => c)
    .Aggregate(Factorial(value.Length), (s, group) => s / Factorial(group.Count()));
}
```

**Demo:** ([Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xx0Zkq))

```
  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "a",
    "aaa",
    "abc",
    "aaab",
    "abracadabra",
    "stackoverflow",
  };

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"{test,20} => {CountAnagrams(test)}"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
                   a => 1
                 aaa => 1
                 abc => 6
                aaab => 4
         abracadabra => 83160
       stackoverflow => 3113510400
```

**Edit:** If you are not allowed to use `System.Numerics` and `System.Linq` you can try using `long`:

```
    private static long Factorial(int value)
    {
        long result = 1;

        for (int i = 2; i <= value; ++i)
            result *= i;

        return result;
    }

    private static long CountAnagrams(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            return 1L;
        
        Dictionary<char, int> groups = new Dictionary<char, int>();

        foreach (var c in value)
            if (groups.TryGetValue(c, out int v))
                groups[c] += 1;
            else
                groups.Add(c, 1);
        
        long result = Factorial(value.Length);
        
        foreach (int v in groups.Values)
            result /= Factorial(v);
        
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I copied your code, but if I write: aaa => 6  ;  aaac =>12

Comment: @Laurențiu Cozma: I've provided **fiddle** in the answer (https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xx0Zkq), could you, please, run it? Does it return 12 instead of 4?

Comment: @Laurențiu Cozma: well, provide your code (say, via .net fiddle) and I'll correct it

Comment: Sorry for waiting, I am beginner and I did not found the share button: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Vx3wbS

Comment: @Laurențiu Cozma: I've put `string tests = "aaab";` instead of `string tests = Console.ReadLine();` and I've got `4` as an answer.  Probably, you have leading / trailing spaces (copy + paste?) we you input the test. Try changing `Console.ReadLine();` into `Console.ReadLine().Trim();`

Comment: Well I do not really know where is the problem. I get the right answers, but the platform where  I have to upload it give the errors I put in comments on dotnet link

Comment: @Laurențiu Cozma: It seems that the site which grades you doesn't allow you to use Linq, I've provided a (simplified?) no Linq. no BigInteger solution: see my Edit

Comment: Now I get this error: CS0246 (Error): Type or namespace name 'Dictionary<,>' could not be found (missing using directive or assembly reference?) (line: 27, character: 8)

Comment: @Laurențiu Cozma: Try adding `using System.Collections.Generic;` or put `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<char, int> groups = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<char, int>();` instead of `Dictionary<char, int> groups = new Dictionary<char, int>();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240348/discussion-between-laureniu-cozma-and-dmitry-bychenko).